# how to have an in-app purchase to remove iAds

Tags: ios

this has been driving me crazy but I'm trying to have an in-app purchase to remove iAds. my app is complete except for this one part and i cant for the life of me figure out how to do this. Ive added the iAds to the app already by means of using the iAd banner in the storyboard then adding the code

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *) banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:error{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

in my .m, the iAd works in my simulator but I'm wanting to have a in-app purchase to remove these. I've already gone through the process in iTunes connect to allow this but i cant figure out the coding in Xcode needed to implement this

ive tried implementing this

```
#define kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier @"put your product id (the one that we just made in iTunesConnect) in here"

- (void)tapsRemoveAds{
NSLog(@"User requests to remove ads");

if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
    NSLog(@"User can make payments");

    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier]];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];

}
else{
    NSLog(@"User cannot make payments due to parental controls");
    //this is called the user cannot make payments, most likely due to parental controls
}
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
int count = [response.products count];
if(count > 0){
    validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Products Available!");
    [self purchase:validProduct];
}
else if(!validProduct){
    NSLog(@"No products available");
    //this is called if your product id is not valid, this shouldn't be called unless that happens.
}
}

- (IBAction)purchase:(SKProduct *)product{
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (IBAction) restore{
//this is called when the user restores purchases, you should hook this up to a button
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{

 NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
{
    if(SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored){
        NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
        //called when the user successfully restores a purchase
        [self doRemoveAds];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
        break;
    }

}

}

  - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
    switch (transaction.transactionState){
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchasing");
            //called when the user is in the process of purchasing, do not add any of your own code here.
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            //this is called when the user has successfully purchased the package (Cha-Ching!)
            [self doRemoveAds]; //you can add your code for what you want to happen when the user buys the purchase here, for this tutorial we use removing ads
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchased");
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
            //add the same code as you did from SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased here
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            //called when the transaction does not finnish
            if(transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Cancelled");
                //the user cancelled the payment ;(
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the user has bought the IAP. If he has done it, remove the iAd view (or setAlpha = 0)

**UPDATE**

The moment the user completes payment (where you receive `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` / `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`, save a flag into `NSUserDefaults`, so that you will know whether the user has bought the IAP, and show/hide the iAd correspondingly.

If there is nothing in `NSUserDefaults`, that means: (1) user hasn't bought the IAP OR (2) user has bought it but somehow the info has been lost in `NSUserDefaults` (e.g. user deleted & reinstalled the app). In either case, the right way to go is to ask the user to buy the IAP. If (2) happens, App Store will automatically restore the IAP, and you will receive a `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`. The code for `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` and `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` should be similar: setting `NSUserDefaults` flag.

To avoid confusion, some apps provide a *Restore* button, which calls `[SKPaymentQueue  restoreCompletedTransactions]` and generate `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` if some IAP has been bought by user. This does nothing if the user hasn't bought any IAP.